# How do I set the headers in azure subscriptions API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I can see in the UI I can add headers:
[image]

But in the documentation for the API it does not mention how I would add this?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/hooks/subscriptions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

Comment: No idea how to do it, but could you manually create one then do a GET? - I imagine part of `consumerInputs` object

Comment: good shout! let me try!

Comment: great it was `httpHeaders`

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to add `httpHeaders` to the `consumerInputs` object field. in the format:

> HTTP header keys and values separated by a colon(e.g. "Key1:value1") with each key-value-pair appearing on its own line of text.

Comment: Maybe give an example/or a source for the quoted documentation?